# Woocommerce purchase date

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a membership site with Woocommerce and need to display how long is left on the membershop, I am guessing I need to do a DB query to get it, but is there a function I have missed that displays the information for a product, I need the product name and date it was purchased by the customer?

thanks in advance

EDIT: I am a bit closer but still not got the order date... it's the only bit of info I need:

```
function customer_membership(){
 global $woocommerce;
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $current_user= wp_get_current_user();
 $customer_email = $current_user->email;

 if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id,'2258')) {

  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop_order',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1'
  );
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $customer_orders = $my_query->posts;
  foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {

   $order = new WC_Order();
   $order->populate($customer_order);
   $orderdata = (array) $order;
   $items = $order->get_items(); 
   foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = '2258';
    if ( $product_id == XYZ ) { 
     echo 'Your membership ends on DATE';
    } // end if product

  } // end orders

 } // endif customer bought

} // end function
```

I have found the extract I need ($order_date) in WC_Abstract_Order but not sure how to use it, can someone help me display the order date in the echo :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your making it way too hard to save and extract that information from the database.

I recommend you use a custom meta field for order, something like this:

```
//Save it after the process
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'purchase_date_save' );
function purchase_date_save( $order_id ) {

    $get_current_date_time = date('Y-m-d');
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_purchase_date', sanitize_text_field( $get_current_date_time ) );
}
```

You can access it like this:

```
$get_value = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'my_purchase_date', true );
```